# Is there a way to disable fingerprint reader on OnePlus 5T?

Tags: lock-screens, fingerprint, oneplus-5t

I'm using a OnePlus 5T, which is running Android 8.1. Since the [face-unlock](/questions/tagged/face-unlock) works perfectly, I don't need the fingerprint reader much. In addition, I often touch the reader accidentally and the phone gets unlocked without my intention.

I only see the following settings related to fingerprint.

[image]

When I click a fingerprint, there are two options:

> - Rename fingerprint
> - Delete fingerprint

I couldn't find any option to disable the fingerprint reader. Actually I don't know what happens when all fingerprints are deleted, but I don't want to delete them.

Is it possible to disable the fingerprint reader without deleting fingerprints?

Edit: I use my fingerprint to sign in to some apps, thus I want to disable fingerprint-unlock only.

Comment: What's holding you off from deleting the fingerprints? Are you using them elsewhere?

Comment: @AndyYan I haven't discovered what else I can or cannot do with the fingerprints yet, so I want to keep them. (P.S. I've been using this phone for 2 days)